# Unique User Input Array List

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class as defined below:

public class CarHireSystem{

private static final Car[] carList = new Car[100];
 private static int carCount = 0;

In this class, I have a menu where the user can add new Car. When they select this option they will be prompted with the following:

```
  System.out.print("Enter car ID: ");
  String carID = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter car description: ");
  String cardescription = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter hire fee: $");
  Double hireFee = sc.nextDouble();
  sc.nextLine();
  carList[carCount] = new Car(carID,carDescription,hireFee);
  carCount++;
```

I would like a way to validate that the car ID entered into the array has not already been entered by the user and print an error message if it has been entered and go back to the main menu. How do I do this without using Hashmap.

Thanks

Comment: Store the input within a `Set`, not array

Comment: I am required to pass the information into an array of references. I can do that with the above code but I want to ensure that ID is unique.

Comment: @kocko Then @newbie123 will need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: Auto generate the id with a running number and don't let the user input the id is one way.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean exists = false;
for (AdventureRide ar : adventureList) {
    if (ar != null && ar.getID().equals(ID)) {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!exists) {
    adventureList[adventureCount++] = new AdventureRide(ID, description, admissionFee);
}
```

Iterate over the array; if an element with the same ID exists, break the `for` loop and set the `exists` flag. Then at the end, check if the `exists` flag has been set. If not, then add the new element into the array.

Comment: Hi I am trying this method but I get a nullpointer exception because nothing is currently in the array. How to get around this?

Comment: doesn't seem to work. It still lets me enter same ID.

Comment: @newbie123 Have you implemented the `AdventureRide.getID()`? What is the return type? If it is `Integer` then it should work; if it is `int` it should be `ar.getID() == ID` instead.

Comment: String ID. I updated my question to a similar one above. Could you please have a look at the new question and help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is already in the list or not, If not add it.

```
List<AdventureRide> list = new List();
AdventureRide ride = new AdventureRide(ID,description,admissionFee);

if(!list.contains(ride))
 list.add(ride);
```

---

If you want to make it with the ID references, you can use a HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer, AdventureRide> = new HashMap();
AdventureRide ride = new AdventureRide(ID,description,admissionFee);
if(!hm.containsKey(ID))
     hm.put(ID,ride);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Go through the array each time you want to enter something and check that the current `ID` is not present within the array.
2. Have your `AdventureRide` override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods such that two elements are the same if they have the same `ID`. Once you have that, replace the array with `Set<AdventureRide>`. This will make sure you have entries with a unique `ID`.

I'd recommend you go for option 2, reason being that:

1. If down the line you need to check some other field, you would just need to change your `equals` and `hashCode` methods.
2. Since the `Set` is a dynamic data structure, you can add/remove from it without knowing the amount of entries before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `Set<String>` to store the ID, and call contains() or get() with a null check. Or store the AdventureRide instances in a `Map<String,AdventureRide>`. For example:

```
Map<String,AdventureRide> adventureMap = new HashMap<String,AdventureRide>();
...
private static final void addNewAdventure()
   {   
      boolean idExists = false;
      System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
      String id;
      do {
        id = sc.nextLine();
        if(null != adventureMap.get(id)) {
          idExists = true;
          System.out.println("The ID you entered already exists.\n Please enter a new ID: ");              
        }
      } while(idExists);
      System.out.print("Enter story: ");
      String description = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter fee: $");
      Double admissionFee = sc.nextDouble(); 
      sc.nextLine();
      adventureMap.put(id, new AdventureRide(id,description,admissionFee));
    //keep track of objects in array
      adventureCount++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can auto generate a unique ID instead of letting user input it. This way, you don't even have to check the duplicated ID.

In your codes, instead of doing this:

```
adventureList[adventureCount] = new AdventureRide(ID,description,admissionFee);
```

Change it to:

```
adventureList[adventureCount] = new AdventureRide(description,admissionFee);
```

Then in your AdventureRide class:

```
class AdventureRide
{
    private static int count = 0;
    private String id;
    public AdventureRide(String desc, double adminFee){
        autoGenerateID(); //Auto generate formatted ID
    }

    private void autoGenerateID(){
        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("T-00000");
        id = fmt.format(count++);
    }
}
```

DecimalFormat to format your ID to specific format. This is of course optional.

**Output:**

```
T-00000
T-00001
T-00002
T-00003
```